# Prediction using words which were not in training in a CNN with pre-trained word embeddings

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

In sentence classification using pre-trained embeddings(fasttext) in a CNN,  how does the CNN predict the category of a sentence when the words were not in the training set?

I think the trained model contains weights, these weights are not updated in the prediction stage, are they?. Then, what happens when the words in the sentence (for which the cnn will predict a category) were not seen in the training? I think they do not have a word vector, only the words that were found in the training.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the FastText embeddings unchanged a do not finetune them during training, it does not really matter that the words were not in the training set as long as they are in the FastText embeddings. After all, this is the biggest advantage of using pre-trained word embeddings.

The important property of the embeddings is that similar words get similar embeddings. The CNN might not have seen the exact same embedding, but similar words probably were in the training data.

Words that are not covered by the pre-trained embeddings, got a common representation for an unknown (out-of-vocabulary, OOV) word. These are usually proper names. It is usually good if you make sure that CNN learns to deal with them already at the training time (you can randomly replace some infrequent words by some random strings) because if the unknown token embedding (that is typically dissimilar to all other embeddings) appears at the inference time and it was never seen at training, it can lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thank you. I was studying your answer. Now, I understand that using embeddings, the model can generalize by similar embeddings, but I would like to know how it works?. I am working with an embedding layer in keras, the embedding matrix in the input contains only vectors for the words in the vocabulary (of the training), then, how can the model generalize when the word was not in the vocabulary, so neither in the embedding matrix? because the OOV words do not have an embedding because they  must have been seen in the training data to have an embedding.  Am I confusing anything?